# java: how to draw lines above painting of canvas

Tags: swing, scala, java-2d

I'm painting some some polygons on to a canvas and want to draw some lines over the painted polygons. If I paint after the line is drawn the painted polygons cover the line up, but if I paint first the line disappears completely. The code is in Scala but I think all the relevant code is from Java libraries.

Edit I've expanded the code in response to Rex Kerr's comment

```
package rStrat
package rSw
package mapCanv
import swing._
import java.awt.geom._
import java.awt.Polygon

abstract class MapCanv [T <: TypesD](val mArea: GeomBase[T]#MapArea) extends Panel
{
   type VHexT <: VisHex  
   val vHexs: Vec[VisHex] = mArea.mHexs.map(i => newVHexT(i))
   def newVHexT(mHex: GeomBase[T]#MapArea#MapHex): VHexT
   val line: Line2D.Double = new Line2D.Double(0,0, 350, 350)

   override def paintComponent (gr2d: Graphics2D)
   {
      super.paintComponent (gr2d)    
      vHexs.foreach(i => i.paint(gr2d))
      gr2d.draw(line)
   }  

    abstract class VisHex (val mHex: GeomBase[T]#MapArea#MapHex) extends Polygon with PaintTr
   {
      mHex.verts.foreach(i => addPoint(i.x.toInt, i.y.toInt))     
   }

   trait PaintTr
   {
      def paint(gr2d: Graphics2D): Unit
   }  
}

package rStrat //separate file
package rSw
package mapCanv
import swing._
//import java.awt._

abstract class MapCanvStd[T <: TypesStd](mArea: GeomBase[T]#MapArea) extends MapCanv[T](mArea)
{
   type VHexT = VisHexStd   
   override def newVHexT(mHex: GeomBase[T]#MapArea#MapHex) = new VisHexStd(mHex)

   class VisHexStd(mHex: GeomBase[T]#MapArea#MapHex) extends VisHex(mHex)
   {
      override def paint(gr2d: Graphics2D): Unit = 
      {          
         gr2d.setPaint(terrToCol(mHex.hex.terr))
         gr2d.fill(this)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working code.  I have thousands of lines of code where I first paint a shape and then draw a line over it, and that works just like you'd expect, so there's almost surely something wrong in your code.  Without a working example, we can't tell where.  For example, you could be setting your color alpha to zero, or you could not be calling the paint method you think you are, or any number of other things.

Comment: @RexKerr I've done a simpler paint and draw and the behaviour is as you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell straight away that your example is not self-contained. For example method `terrToCol` in the `paint` body of `VisHexStd` is nowhere defined. I take that you know the basics about [Swing/Java2D painting](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html).

The `Graphics2D` handle is a stateful/mutable thing. So when changing the order of nested painting produces unexpected results, it's due to changes to the graphics state made in those painting commands. All `draw` or `fill` commands take the color or paint state from the graphics handle (`Paint` being a super/more general interface of `Color`).

In your main `paintComponent` method you do not set the color/paint, relying on the default (the component's foreground color). But the `paint` method of `VisHex` which you call repeatedly in the iteration does change the paint property (`setPaint`), so the `gr2d.draw(line)` in the main method just uses whatever arbitrary last paint you set.

Try adding `gr2d.setColor(getForeground)` before the `gr2d.draw(line)` statement.

Comment: Yes I've found the problem as indicated in my own answer, but I've given you the correct answer for your efforts, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah it was my silly mistake. I wasn't aware that draw even used the setcolor method. I just presumed that it drew black lines, which of course it does by default. The polygon examples I had found all used the setcolor method but the draw examples didn't. I was using a very light colour for my polygons which showed up fine for the Polygons but was virtually invisible when used as a line.